# Can't convert from one data type to the same?

Tags: c++, templates, set

I'm trying to implement my own Set template, and have issues with trying to do a breadth-  first search using my Queue template that works independently.

The weird part is that I get this error in my Set template when trying to compile. Why can't it convert from one pointer to a different one that is the same data type?

```
error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'Set<T>::Node<T> *' to 'Set<T>::Node<T> *'
      with
      [
          T=std::string
      ]
      Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
      c:\users\programming\Set\Set.h(96) : while compiling class template member function 'void Set<T>::print(Set<T>::Node<T> *)'
      with
      [
          T=std::string
      ]
      c:\users\programming\Set\main.cpp(13) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Set<T>' being compiled
      with
      [
          T=std::string
      ]
```

Queue Class Template

```
template <typename T>
class Queue
...
T* front()
{
    if (first != NULL)
        return first->item;
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Set Class Template

```
template <typename T>
Class Set
...
Queue<Node<T> *> q;
void print(Node<T> *p)
{
    q.push(p);
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        cout << p->item << "(" << p->height << ") ";
        if (p->left != NULL)
            q.push(p->left);
        if (p->right != NULL)
            q.push(p->right);
        if (!q.size())
        {
            // Error is at this line
            p = q.front();
            q.pop();
        }
        else
            p = NULL;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: _cannot convert from 'Set<T>::Node<T> *' to 'Set<T>::Node<T> *'_ **with `T = ...` and `T = ...`_**

Comment: I suspect that isn't the entire error message. What is the type of `q` and what does `front` return?

Comment: Maybe `q` is a set of pointer-to-const?

Comment: I've included the missing information I'll copy the whole error message I didn't noticed it was on multiple lines. I've also looked to see if there was a possibly of it becoming a const but couldn't see where that might be causing the issue.

Comment: Grrr... what line generates the error? Why not post that?

Comment: @EitanT I did if you look in the code I have a comment saying // Error is at this line

Comment: @LF4 Oh, missed that. I take it back.

Comment: @LF4, can you add declaration of `first` in `class Queue` and `item` in `first`.

Comment: The code as posted is OK (which means that I have made it compile by adding missing declarations *only*). The problem is elsewhere. Post a complete minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Oops... I didn't see the definition of `front` and assumed it returns by value. That's exactly the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Queue` class is instantiated with a `Node<T>*` type already ... you are then attempting to return a pointer to a type `T` from your `Queue<T>::front` method.  If you are instantating your `Queue<T>` class with `T=Node<T>*`, then you only need to return a type `T` from your `front` method, not a `T*`. So change your `front` method signature to the following:

```
template <typename T>
class Queue
...
T front()
{
    if (first != NULL)
        return first->item;
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Now this could cause you a bunch of problems if `T` was not a pointer type ... therefore you  may want to create a specialization of your `Queue<T>::front` method for cases where `T` is already a pointer type.  For instance:

```
//pointer-type specialization
template<typename T>
T Queue<T*>::front()
{
    if (first != NULL)
        return first->item;
    else
        return NULL;
}

//non-specialized version where T is not a pointer-type
template<typename T>
T* Queue<T>::front()
{
    if (first != NULL)
        return &(first->item);
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Comment: `front` should probably return a *reference* to the element (to be consistent with `front` on the standard library components).

Comment: Thanks I'm still new to templates, my Queue, Stack and Set are how I'm learning with them.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas What happens if the queue is empty?  I understand that with `std::queue` the assumption is that you cannot call `front` on an empty queue, but in this case his `Queue` class is setup so that `front` can be called when the queue is empty.

Comment: In the standard library it is undefined behavior to call `front` (or `back`) on an empty container. But I see what you say, I had not realized that in his design calling `front` on an empty container is well defined...

Comment: @Jason: you should return a reference to a dummy object, then.

Comment: @KubaOber True, but that would make two different interfaces for `front` if `T` is or isn't a pointer type.  This way keeps the interface the same (i.e., you will always get a pointer back from `front` that points to a type `T`).

Comment: @Jason: How? If you use any standard container, you'll gladly get a default-constructed pointer type if pointer types are what you store in your container. It will be a null pointer, in other words. It's idiomatic C++, it's probably bad style to do it your way: it'll confuse people who are used to STL-style container concepts.

Comment: @KubaOber I see what you're saying, but the OP's interface is not STL-style since he wants defined behavior for an empty queue. I agree with you, in that if I were to personally design an interface from scratch, I would want to maintain STL compatibility, but that is not what the OP has done.  Additionally, a "dummy" object can be somewhat arbitrary, thus leading to hidden errors where a "dummy" is returned and used as a normal object when there were in-fact no objects left in the queue.  This is why Java-style interfaces will typically throw an exception rather than a dummy object.